# How was the scalar form of Gauss's theorem (divergence theorem) in multivariate calculus derived and what was the motivation for inventing it?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, divergence-theorem

[the scalar form of Gauss formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpyMW.png)

∰_Ω〖(∂P/∂x+∂Q/∂y+∂R/∂z)dv〗=∯_Σ〖Pdydz+Qdzdx+Rdxdy〗=∯_Σ〖(Pcosα+Qcosβ+Rcosγ)dS〗

After checking the history information, the original prototype of Gauss's theorem was proposed by Lagrange in the seventeenth century. When studying fluids, there was the idea of ​​converting between volume fraction and area fraction. Then Gauss came up with a special form of the theorem in 1813, and finally, in 1826, Michael Ostrogradsky of Russia gave the scalar general form of the divergence theorem in Cartesian coordinates. But they did not have the concept of divergence when they arrived at this theorem. Divergence is a concept in a vector. It is a word created by Maxwell in studying electromagnetic fields. It was originally called convergence and then divergence.

Therefore, from a mathematical point of view, why invent a conversion theorem between triple integral and double integral？ Is it to simplify the triple integral operation？

From a scalar point of view, I don’t understand why three multivariate functions"P(x,y,z)、Q（x,y,z）、R(x,y,z)" should be introduced into the formula.

In addition,why construct such a form of "∂P/∂x+∂Q/∂y+∂R/∂z"in the formula? How did this form come out?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you want to compute the flux of a vector field through a closed surface $S$, chop up the volume enclosed by the surface into tiny boxes, compute the flux of the vector field through the surface of each box, and add it all up. When you compute the flux through the surface of a tiny box, you discover the divergence formula. This argument is often given in detail in physics textbooks—for example, I believe Feynman presents this derivation of the divergence theorem in volume 2 of the Feynman lectures on physics.